# how to pass unknown argument to a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm assigning a data frame to a variable name taken from a string.
So when I run the code I don't know what the variable name will be.
I want to pass that data frame to another function to plot it. How can I pass it to the function without knowing its name?

```
file_name <- file.choose()
fname  <- unlist (strsplit (file_name, "\\", fixed = TRUE))
fname  <- fname[length(fname)]
waf_no <- unlist (strsplit (fname, "\\s"))
waf_no <- waf_no[grep(waf_no, pattern="WAF")]
data <- read_WAF_file (file_name)
assign(waf_no, flux_calc(data)) #flux calc() calculates and manipulates the data frame
plot_waf(?)
```

my plot_waf function is very simple

```
plot_waf <- function (dataframe) {
library("ggplot2")
qplot(dist,n2o,data=dataframe,shape=treat)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inverse for `assign` is `get`:

> Search by name for an object (`get`) or zero or more objects (`mget`).

Therefore, you'll need to run your plot function like this:

```
plot_waf(get(waf_no))
```

Comment: So simple yet elusive.
Thanks!.
But what do I write in the function line and in the call for the qplot? (where I wrote "dataframe")

Comment: Ok, I just passed waf_no to the function and in the function I used Get(waf_no) inside the qplot.